# REST service and big files

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, soap

Can `REST` web service (which usually produces e.g. simple `JSONs`) both handle and return big binary input/output data?

I mean, to call a `REST` service by a HTTP POST providing big file and afterwards reading the big result back? Is REST ok for that? ("Big" = few megabytes)

Comment: The REST architecture is not limited to any media types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With text serializers such as JSON and XML you would get about 33% increase of the size of the files over the wire as the binary data needs to be Base64 encoded. There are more optimized protocols such as [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism) to handle this scenario. [WCF supports MTOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209.aspx) out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. One question, does JSON have the binary data support at all?

Comment: @James, JSON is text so you will need to encode the binary data to some text representation which usually is Base64 leading to a significant increase in the message size.

Comment: And without JSON, can REST return the binary data "directly" using HTTP GET?

Comment: @James, of course. What do you think happens when you click on some link on a website pointing to a binary file to download? You are sending a GET request to the server which responds to this GET request by directly writing the binary contents of the file in the response. Your browser uses the Content-Disposition response header to either display the file inline or prompt you to save it somewhere.

Comment: MTOM/XOP is the domain of SOAP rather than REST, no?

Answer (score 3):

REST architectures are quite capable of using HTTP to serve up `application/octet-stream`, which is just a stream of bytes.  HTTP can quite reliably serve very large files.

Answer (score 2):

Since REST is primarily a service over HTTP, standard advantages and limitations of HTTP apply to REST services too.  You can send large files of few MBs as POST to REST API in a way similar that one uploads a large file to a web app.